# creating pandas data frame from multiple files

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a pandas `DataFrame` and it works fine for a single file. If I need to build it for multiple files which have the same data structure. So instead of single file name I have a list of file names from which I would like to create the `DataFrame`.

Not sure what's the way to append to current `DataFrame` in pandas or is there a way for pandas to suck a list of files into a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The pandas `concat` command is your friend here. Lets say you have all you files in a directory, targetdir. You can:

1. make a list of the files
2. load them as pandas dataframes
3. and concatenate them together

`

```
import os
import pandas as pd

#list the files
filelist = os.listdir(targetdir) 
#read them into pandas
df_list = [pd.read_table(file) for file in filelist]
#concatenate them together
big_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: Glob would be perfect for the first step.  You can generate a list of files using wildcards.

Comment: In my use case, I needed to do `pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True, axis=1)` since each csv file represented a column

Answer (score 3):

Potentially horribly inefficient but...

Why not use `read_csv`, to build two (or more) dataframes, then use join to put them together?

That said, it would be easier to answer your question if you provide some data or some of the code you've used thus far.

Answer (score 1):

I might try to concatenate the files before feeding them to pandas. If you're in Linux or Mac you could use `cat`, otherwise a very simple Python function could do the job for you.

Comment: Sure.. just curious if there is a way to do this without combining all the files. Thanks for your quick reply Jose

Answer (score 0):

Are these files in a csv format. You could use the read_csv.
http://pandas.sourceforge.net/io.html

Once you have read the files and save it in two dataframes, you could merge the two dataframes or add additional columns to one of the two dataframes( assuming common index). Pandas should be able to fill in missing rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd
data = []

thisdir = os.getcwd()

for r, d, f in os.walk(thisdir):
    for file in f:
        if ".docx" in file:
            data.append(file)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That’s especially important here where there are four other answers, including an accepted answer, competing for attention. When might your approach be preferable? Has the syntax changed since the original answer nine years ago?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that avoids using a list to hold all the data frames, if you don't need them in a list, it creates a dataframe for each file, you can then `pd.concat` them.

```
import fnmatch

# get the CSV files only
files = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('.'), '*.csv')
files
```

Output which is now a list of the names:

```
['Feedback Form Submissions 1.21-1.25.22.csv',
 'Feedback Form Submissions 1.21.22.csv',
 'Feedback Form Submissions 1.25-1.31.22.csv']
```

Now create a simple list of new names to make working with them easier:

```
# use a simple format
names = []
for i in range(0,len(files)):
    names.append('data' + str(i))
names

['data0', 'data1', 'data2']
```

You can use any list of names that you want.  The next step take the file names and the list of names and then assign them to the names.

```
# i is the incrementor for the list of names
i = 0

# iterate through the file names
for file in files:
    # make an empty dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    # load the first file in
    df = pd.read_csv(file, low_memory=False)
    # get the first name from the list, this will be a string
    new_name = names[i]
    # assign the string to the variable and assign it to the dataframe 
    locals()[new_name] = df.copy()
    # increment the list of names
    i = i + 1
```

You now have 3 separate dataframes named data0, data1, data2, and do commands like

```
data2.info()
```