# Python pandas - Combine columns from different files

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CSV files. They actually have over 2 million records in each, but here's a simplified version:

File 1 :

```
col1
----
1
54
744
45
65
```

File 2 :

```
col2
----
sdf
322
d3
d
2
```

What is the quickest way of combining the two of these to end up with the following?

```
col1  |  col2
-------------
1     |  sdf
54    |  322
744   |  d3
45    |  d
65    |  2
```

I would usually use Excel or similar but the dataset is too large to load. Is there something in Pandas I can use to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545957/creating-pandas-data-frame-from-multiple-files

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("csv1")
df2 = pd.read_csv("csv2")

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

This should do the trick